# Infer type from sibling

Tags: typescript

I am writing some middleware with the following interface

```
interface Config {
    callApi<P> (api: ApiClient): Promise<P>,
    transformResponse?(payload: P): any
}
```

From the above,  you can see that the config takes a `callApi` function which will call an remote APi and return the promise-based result, and then and optional `transformResponse` that will receive the payload, and apply a transformation to it. The key part is that the `transformResponse` function should infer the type of the payload, based on the return type of the `callApi` call

Problem is that the above is not valid, because the `P` type inside `transformResponse` can not reach the same variable for the `callApi` function.

Is there any way to accomplish the above, without having to pass in the API response type like this

```
interface Config<ApiResponse> {
    callApi (api: ApiClient): Promise<ApiResponse>,
    transformResponse?(payload: ApiResponse): any
}
```

Example usage

```
const callCreateComment: Config = {
  callApi (api) => api.createComment(),
  transformResponse(payload) => ({ ...payload // infer the return type of the `api.createComment()` call })
}
```

Comment: This feels like you're asking for [existential types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), but I'm not sure.  Can you show how you are going to use this and how you want to be *prevented* from using it?  Obviously you can just return a `Promise<any>` and use `payload: any`, but there's something you're trying to enforce I guess.  Do you really mean `Config<Result>`'s `callApi()` function to allow the *caller* to specify `P`?  Or is it that `callApi()` will return some unknown-to-the-caller `P` that must be accepted by `transformResponse` on the same object?

Comment: I removed the Result type to clean up the example. 

The main point is that I want to be able to infer/auto-complete the return type of API call inside the `transformResponse` function, without having to manually specify its return type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand what you want, which is to write out the `callApi()` method and then have TypeScript use the return type of that method to constrain the parameter of the `transformResponse()` method.  I can't figure out how to get the inference to work with an object literal.  It looks like the generic `ApiResponse` parameter hasn't been resolved in time to contextually constrain the type of the argument to `transformResponse()`.

The way I can get the inference to work is to break the object literal into two pieces and have a function take those pieces as arguments and put them together.  This lets us take advantage of the [left-to-right inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15680#issuecomment-307571917) for contextually-typed function parameters.  It will probably make more sense just to show you:

I'm going to assume something like these definitions for you, since you didn't specify them:

```
interface Comment {
    something: string; // who knows
}
interface ApiClient {
    createComment(): Promise<Comment>;
}
```

And I will give some type aliases to the methods of `Config` so I can reuse them:

```
type CallApi<R> = (api: ApiClient) => Promise<R>;
type TransformResponse<R> = (payload: R) => any;
```

Finally, here's your `Config<R>`, which is actually the same as your (edited) version with `R` instead of `ApiResponse`:

```
interface Config<R> {
    callApi: CallApi<R>,
    transformResponse?: TransformResponse<R>
}
```

So here's the function that makes inference work:

```
const buildConfig = <R>(
    callApi: CallApi<R>, 
    transformResponse?: TransformResponse<R>
): Config<R> => ({ callApi, transformResponse });
```

The `buildConfig()` function takes two arguments.  The first is a `CallApi<R>` and the second is a `TransformResponse<R>`. The left-to-right contextual type inference for function arguments means it will resolve `R` from the first argument and then use it in the contextual type for the second argument.  Like so:

```
const callCreateComment = buildConfig(
    (api) => api.createComment(),  // R is inferred as Comment
    (payload) => ({ ...payload })  // payload is now constrained
);
```

You will notice that as you type that in, the contextual type of `payload` will be inferred as a `Comment`.  And `callCreateComment` is typed as `Config<Comment>` without your having to specify `Comment` anywhere in that function, as desired.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Comment%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20comment%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ApiClient%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20createComment%28%29%3A%20Promise%3CComment%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20CallApi%3CR%3E%20%3D%20%28api%3A%20ApiClient%29%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CR%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20TransformResponse%3CR%3E%20%3D%20%28payload%3A%20R%29%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20Config%3CR%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callApi%3A%20CallApi%3CR%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20transformResponse%3F%3A%20TransformResponse%3CR%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20buildConfig%20%3D%20%3CR%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callApi%3A%20CallApi%3CR%3E%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20transformResponse%3F%3A%20TransformResponse%3CR%3E%0D%0A%29%3A%20Config%3CR%3E%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20callApi%2C%20transformResponse%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20callCreateComment%20%3D%20buildConfig%28%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28api%29%20%3D%3E%20api.createComment%28%29%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28payload%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20...payload%20%7D%29%0D%0A%29%3B%0D%0A)

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic and exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated. Only thing missing is that that the payload is (correctly) inferred as being the Promise<R> where I'd like to have it return just the unwrapped value <R>, not the promise.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm, `payload` is definitely inferred as just `R`.  The return value of `callApi()` is `Promise<R>`, but that's the type definition you specified.  If you meant for it to return just `R` you can change the type singature.  If you're asking how to take a `Promise<R>` and turn it into an `R`, then that's a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/2887218) which has been asked many times, and the short answer is "you can't".  The longer answer is "you will need to use async techniques instead".

Comment: You're right, I got it working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can turn Promise<R> into R using Awaited<Promise<R>>